# Update database table based on textbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, ado.net

I am trying to update database table based on text-box values.But i am unable to get new modified values in database.

Here is my code which displays information in text-boxes coming from database

```
protected void Info()
{
    string sID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
    string sSql = "select * from [fn_Items]('"+sID+"')";
    DataTable tbl1 = new DataTable();
    string sEr = myClass.FillupTable(sSql, ref tbl1);
    if (tbl1.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        DataRow rd = tbl1.Rows[0];
        txtName.Text = rd["Name"].ToString();
        txtCategory.Text = rd["Category"].ToString();
        DateTime mStart;
        DateTime mFinish;
        Boolean b = false;

        b = DateTime.TryParse(rd["start"].ToString(), out mStart);
        b = DateTime.TryParse(rd["end"].ToString(), out mFinish);
        txtStart.Text = mStart.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        txtend.Text = mFinish.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
        txtDescription.Text = rd["Description"].ToString();

    }
}
```

Now when the user modifies the text-box data and clicks save, the data should change in the database. Here is my click_event:

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new 
        SqlConnection("Data Source=MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=Items_2;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=password"))
    {

        string query = "UPDATE tbl_Items SET Name = @Name,Category=@Category,start = @start, end = @End,Description = @Description where ID = @ID ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",txtID.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", Category.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start", txtStart.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end",txtend.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error " + ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Here while updating, in text-boxes I am getting the values present in the database where I need to get the modified values. How do I get the modified values instead?

Comment: When debugging, do you see the values in the click event?  Are you sure they are labeled correctly?

Comment: When Iam debugging I am getting the previous values which are from Info() .  I am not getting the values that are changed.

Comment: On a side note, you should validate your text inputs. Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injections. For example, let's say that in txtID.Text, I input the value `12345' drop table tbl_items `, I would be able to drop your table.

Comment: If the click event doesn't show the current values, then running the script will not update the db with those values either.  You have to fix that first.

Comment: I'll take a swing. :) You need !IsPostBack in Page Load event like - Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { if (!IsPostBack)  { Info(); }}

Comment: Yes that is what my problem is,,I can't understand why click event doesn't show the current values

Comment: Please see my explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank You @Win   yes i forgot to add Ispostback in my page load...Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Page load event fire first before firing Click event of btnSave. Using [IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.web.ui.page.ispostback%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) eliminate that problem.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     Info();
   }
}
```